# Configuring GeoServer on AWS to serve Cloud Optimized GeoTIFFs (COGs) from S3

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I want to use S3 buckets as data stores for ImageMosaics on GeoServer in AWS.  I'm using the [Support for S3 GeoTIFF](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/s3-geotiff/index.html) and the [ImageMosaic](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html) module. I'm using geoserver 2.16.

First of all, is this possible?

The S3 Support module documentation is a bit thin, but it states that you can refer to images using a convention from the module configuration file.

Is it possible to use that convention for each granule in the image mosaic?

Also, the configuration file for the S3 module requires a username and password.

What account is this referring to?

If I have enabled programmatic access for the EC2 instance to read and write to the S3 bucket, why would I need a user name and password?

Comment: I wonder did you ever find a solution to get this to work? I am currently looking into similar functionality.